# Weird WebRTC SinkID issue

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, webrtc

I have 8 Virtual Audio lines. I'm trying to map different audio/video players to different Virtual lines as we use this for Remote Interpretation. My problem is when a new WebRTC appears, all the players default to the newest sinkID kind of. The sink ID's report they didn't change, but all the audio starts flowing through the most recent set sinkID. Does anyone know if this is a browser limitation or something?

This only happens when I create audio players on demand when people connect. There is no issue if I set the ID's after everyone is connected.  I even try resetting all the sinkID's to be what they should with each new connection but the audio still all flows through the SinkID on the newest audio player.

I've attached a view of how everything looks. In the attached, Dave would be attached to the SinkID for Line 4. This works great. If another interpreter joins Tagalog, they can also be heard on line 4. The problem is, if someone joins lets say Spanish, when I set the sink ID for the player on Spanish (Line 3), all audio is heard through the SinkID of line 3 even though the SinkID's for the people on line 4 is still set to line 4.  I'm thinking this might be a Chrome Bug. I'm using OpenTok (tokbox), some PHP which doesn't really need to be shown to manage what languages show up. I've attached the iFrame code that is managing all of this.

[image: View of Interface]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IRIS Remote Player</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <link href="/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="lastLoaded" content="2020-04-21 11:34:57">
    <script> var EnglishOn; </script>
<style>
  .slow  .toggle-group { transition: left 0.7s; -webkit-transition: left 0.7s; }
  .fast  .toggle-group { transition: left 0.1s; -webkit-transition: left 0.1s; }
  .quick .toggle-group { transition: none;      -webkit-transition: none; }
</style>    
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger form-control" id="connect">Connect Remote Interpreters</button>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row live" style="display:none;background:black;color:white;padding-bottom:5px">
        <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" checked data-width="100%" id="AllAudio" data-toggle="toggle" data-offstyle="danger" data-onstyle="success" data-on="Live" data-off="Break" data-style="quick"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" checked data-width="100%" id="Admins" data-toggle="toggle" data-offstyle="danger" data-onstyle="success" data-on="Admins Live" data-off="Admins Off" data-style="quick"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row live" style="display:none;background:#fff;color:black">
<div class="col-sm-2" id="PL"><input data-style="quick" type="checkbox" class="Interpretation AudioControl SwitchPL" data-width="100%" id="floorPolish" data-lang="PL" data-toggle="toggle" checked  data-offstyle="danger" data-onstyle="success" data-on="Polish" data-off="Floor"><br />Floor<br /><audio autoplay controls muted id="englishPolish" class="englishPL"></audio></div><div class="col-sm-2" id="RU"><input data-style="quick" type="checkbox" class="Interpretation AudioControl SwitchRU" data-width="100%" id="floorRussian" data-lang="RU" data-toggle="toggle" checked  data-offstyle="danger" data-onstyle="success" data-on="Russian" data-off="Floor"><br />Floor<br /><audio autoplay controls muted id="englishRussian" class="englishRU"></audio></div><div class="col-sm-2" id="ES"><input data-style="quick" type="checkbox" class="Interpretation AudioControl SwitchES" data-width="100%" id="floorSpanish" data-lang="ES" data-toggle="toggle" checked  data-offstyle="danger" data-onstyle="success" data-on="Spanish" data-off="Floor"><br />Floor<br /><audio autoplay controls muted id="englishSpanish" class="englishES"></audio></div><div class="col-sm-2" id="TL"><input data-style="quick" type="checkbox" class="Interpretation AudioControl SwitchTL" data-width="100%" id="floorTagalog" data-lang="TL" data-toggle="toggle" checked  data-offstyle="danger" data-onstyle="success" data-on="Tagalog" data-off="Floor"><br />Floor<br /><audio autoplay controls muted id="englishTagalog" class="englishTL"></audio></div><div class="col-sm-2" id="EN"><input type="checkbox" data-style="quick" class="AudioControl" data-width="100%" id="floorEnglish" data-toggle="toggle" data-offstyle="danger" data-onstyle="success" data-on="English" data-off="Floor"><br />Floor<br /><audio autoplay controls muted id="englishEnglish" class="englishEN"></audio></div>
    </div>
</div>




<script>
var audioSource;
var vars = {};
var floorSource;

$('#connect').click(function() {

    $('input:checkbox#Admins').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.ADMIN').each(function() {
                var adminID = $(this).attr("id");
                var thisID = adminID.replace("userID", "");
                $("#"+thisID).prop('muted', false);
                $('#'+thisID).prop('volume', 1);                    
            });         
        } else {
            $('.ADMIN').each(function() {
                var adminID = $(this).attr("id");
                var thisID = adminID.replace("userID", "");
                $("#"+thisID).prop('muted', true);
                $('#'+thisID).prop('volume', 0);                    
            });             
        }   
    });
    $('input:checkbox.AudioControl').change(function(){
        var LanguageCode = $(this).attr("data-lang");
        var LanguageName = $(this).attr("data-on");
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#english"+LanguageName).prop('muted', true);
            $('#english'+LanguageName).prop('volume', 0);   
            $("."+LanguageCode).prop('muted', false);
            $('.'+LanguageCode).prop('volume', 1);
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                if ($('#Admins').is(':checked')) {} else {
                    $('.ADMIN').each(function() {
                        var adminID = $(this).attr("id");
                        var thisID = adminID.replace("userID", "");             
                        $("#"+thisID).prop('muted', true);
                        $('#'+thisID).prop('volume', 0);    
                    }); 
                }   
            }, 200);
        } else {
            //Activate Floor
            $("#english"+LanguageName).prop('muted', false);
            $('#english'+LanguageName).prop('volume', 1);   
            $("."+LanguageCode).prop('muted', true);
            $('.'+LanguageCode).prop('volume', 0);
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                if ($('#Admins').is(':checked')) {} else {
                    $('.ADMIN').each(function() {
                        var adminID = $(this).attr("id");
                        var thisID = adminID.replace("userID", "");             
                        $("#"+thisID).prop('muted', true);
                        $('#'+thisID).prop('volume', 0);
                    });                 
                }       
            }, 200);                
        }
    });

    $('input:checkbox#AllAudio').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.Interpretation').bootstrapToggle('on')
            $('#floorEnglish').bootstrapToggle('off')
        } else {
            $('.AudioControl').bootstrapToggle('off')       
        }
    }); 

    $("#connect").hide();
    $("#subscriber").show();
    $(".live").show();
playFloor('Polish','PL');
        playFloor('Russian','RU');
        playFloor('Spanish','ES');
        playFloor('Tagalog','TL');
            playFloor('English', 'EN');

    function playFloor(language, code) {
        const audio = document.getElementById('english'+language);
        const constraints = {
            audio: {deviceId: floorSource},
            video: false
        };
        function handleSuccess(stream) {
          const audioTracks = stream.getAudioTracks();
          console.log('Got stream with constraints:', constraints);
          console.log('Using audio device: ' + audioTracks[0].label);
          stream.oninactive = function() {
            console.log('Stream ended');
          };
          window.stream = stream; // make variable available to browser console
          audio.srcObject = stream;
        }

        function handleError(error) {
          alert('navigator.MediaDevices.getUserMedia error: ', error.message, error.name);
        }

        newSinkID = vars[code];

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError);


        //const MyEnglishAudio = document.getElementById("englishPlayer");
        audio.setSinkId(newSinkID);
        console.log("Setting Audio to: "+newSinkID);

        if(code == "EN") {  
            $("#englishEnglish").prop('muted', false);
            $('#englishEnglish').prop('volume', 1); 
            console.log("Setting English Volume on "+floorSource);
        }       
    }
        function handleRemoteError(error) {
          if (error) {
            alert(error);
          }
        }




    var apiKey = 'HIDEEN';
    var sessionId = 'HIDDEN';
    var token = 'HIDDEN';

    socket = io.connect('/', {
        secure: true,
        'reconnection': true,
        'reconnectionDelay': 1000,
        'reconnectionAttempts': Infinity
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log("Disconnected from the server"); 
            //location.reload(true);            
        }); 

     socket.on('send', function (msg) {
         fromSocket = msg.split(" ");
         to_meeting_id = fromSocket[0];
         to_lang = fromSocket[1];
         action = fromSocket[2];
         who = fromSocket[3];

    if(to_meeting_id == '17') {      
        console.log("Action by "+who+": "+action+" for "+to_lang);
        var info = msg.split(" ");
        console.log("0: "+info[0]+" 1: "+info[1]+" 2: "+info[2]+" 3: "+info[3]+" 4:"+info[4]+" 5: "+info[5]+" 6: "+info[6]+" 7: "+info[7]);

        if(action == "english") {
            $('#floorEnglish').bootstrapToggle('on');
            $('.Switch'+info[7]).bootstrapToggle('off');
            useraudio = document.getElementById(who);
            MynewSinkID = vars['EN'];
            //useraudio.setSinkId(MynewSinkID);
            useraudio.setSinkId(MynewSinkID)
            .then(() => {
              console.log('successfully set the audio output device - Note Unmuting '+who);
                    $("#"+who).prop('muted', false);
                    $('#'+who).prop('volume', 1);
                    $('#'+who).css("background-color", "green");                    
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.error('Failed to set the audio output device ', err);
            });
        }
        if(action == "englishOff") {
            $('#floorEnglish').bootstrapToggle('off');
            $('.Switch'+info[6]).bootstrapToggle('on');
            // Set Sink Audio Back
            useraudio = document.getElementById(who);
            MynewSinkID = vars[info[6]];
            //useraudio.setSinkId(MynewSinkID);
            useraudio.setSinkId(MynewSinkID)
            .then(() => {
              console.log('successfully set the audio output device');
                    $('#'+who).css("background-color", "white");      
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.error('Failed to set the audio output device ', err);
            });         
        }   
            if(action == "privacyOn") {
                $('#floor'+info[4]).bootstrapToggle('off');
            }
            if(action == "privacyOff") {
                $('#floor'+info[4]).bootstrapToggle('on');
            }
    }

    }); 

    console.log("Starting Session");
      var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);
        var AllUsers = [];
        i = 0;
      // Subscribe to a newly created stream
      session.on('streamCreated', function streamCreated(event) {
        console.log("New stream in the session: " + event.stream.streamId);
        var subscriberOptions = {
          insertMode: 'append',
          insertDefaultUI: false,
          subscribeToAudio: true,
          showControls: true,
          width: 400,
          height: 100,
          subscribeToVideo: false
        };

        console.log("STARTING LOG OF EVENT");
        console.log(event);
        console.log("END LOG OF EVENT");
        parms = event.stream.connection.data;
        //alert(parms)
        newparms = parms.split(",");
        ConnectingID = newparms[0];
        Channel = newparms[1];
        subscriber = session.subscribe(event.stream, subscriberOptions, handleRemoteError);
        console.log("Connecting to event stream: "+event.stream);
        //console.log("My Lang: "+MyLang+" VS "+Channel);
        item = {}
        item ["Channel"] = Channel;
        item ["RemoteUserID"] = ConnectingID;
        item ["RemoteStream"] = event.stream;
        // See if we have seen this user before. If so, remove them from the array so we can readd them after with new stream info
        jQuery.each(AllUsers, function(i, val) {
           if(val.RemoteUserID == ConnectingID) // delete index
           {
              //AllUsers.splice(i, 1); // Remove previous streams by this user
          }
        });
        AllUsers.push(item);
        console.log(AllUsers);

    subscriber.on('videoElementCreated', (event) => {
        //console.log("Info "+event.target.stream.connection.data);
        var connectionData = event.target.stream.connection.data;
        var info = connectionData.split(",")
        console.log("User ID: "+info[0]);
        console.log("Lang: "+info[1]);
        $('#userID'+info[0]).remove();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            timeout: 10000,
            url: '/ajax/who.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { "user_id": info[0] },
            cache: false,               
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                var msg = '';
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    msg = 'Can not reach network.\n Verify you have internet.';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 403) {
                    msg = 'Your five digit code did not match. ';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    msg = 'Time out error.';
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                } else {
                    msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                }
                alert("Local Server Request: "+msg);                        
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#'+info[1]).append(data);
                document.getElementById(info[1]).appendChild(event.element);
                setTimeout(function(){          
                    if (data.indexOf('ADMIN') > -1) {
                        if ($('#Admins').is(':checked')) {} else {
                            $("#"+info[0]).prop('muted', true);
                            $('#'+info[0]).prop('volume', 0);
                        }
                    }
                }, 200);
            }
        });         

        console.log("Video Element Created");
        console.log(event);
        dynamicSinkID = vars[info[1]];
        //alert(dynamicSinkID);
        event.element.setAttribute("class", "InterpreationSource "+info[1]);
        event.element.setAttribute("data-lang", info[1]);
        event.element.setAttribute("id", info[0]);
        event.element.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
        event.element.setAttribute("width", "300");
        event.element.setAttribute("height", "54");
      if (typeof event.element.sinkId !== 'undefined') {
        event.element.setSinkId(dynamicSinkID)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('successfully set the audio output device');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error('Failed to set the audio output device ', err);
        });
      } else {
        console.warn('device does not support setting the audio output');
      }



      // FIX FOR CHROME BUG SETTING LAST PLAYER CREATED AS THE SINKID FOR All - FAILED
      /*
      setTimeout(function(){
            $('.InterpreationSource').each(function() {

                var playerID = $(this).attr("id");
                var lang_code = $(this).attr("data-lang"); // Get language of each player
                var FixID = vars[lang_code]; // Get SinkID it's supposed to be
                var theFix = document.getElementById(playerID);
                console.log("Fixing "+playerID+" with "+FixID);
                theFix.setSinkId(FixID)
                .then(() => {
                  console.log('successfully set the audio output device - Note Unmuting '+playerID);    
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                  console.error('Failed to set the audio output device ', err);
                });                 
            });     

        }, 2000);
        */      
      // END FIX BUG FOR CHROME

    });         

      });

    session.connect(token, function (error) {
        if(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    }); 



});


if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices) {
  console.log("enumerateDevices() not supported.");
}

// List cameras and microphones.

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
.then(function(devices) {
  devices.forEach(function(device) {
    //console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +" id = " + device.deviceId);
    if(device.kind == "audiooutput" && device.label == "Line 5 (Virtual Audio Cable)") {
        vars['EN'] = device.deviceId;
        console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +" id = " + device.deviceId);
    }
    if(device.kind == "audiooutput" && device.label == "Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable)") {
        vars['PL'] = device.deviceId;
        console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +" id = " + device.deviceId);
    }
    if(device.kind == "audiooutput" && device.label == "Line 2 (Virtual Audio Cable)") {
        vars['RU'] = device.deviceId;
        console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +" id = " + device.deviceId);
    }
    if(device.kind == "audiooutput" && device.label == "Line 3 (Virtual Audio Cable)") {
        vars['ES'] = device.deviceId;
        console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +" id = " + device.deviceId);
    }
    if(device.kind == "audiooutput" && device.label == "Line 4 (Virtual Audio Cable)") {
        vars['TL'] = device.deviceId;
        console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +" id = " + device.deviceId);
    }
    if(device.kind == "audioinput" && device.label == "Microphone Array (Synaptics Audio)") {
        floorSource = device.deviceId;
        console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +" id = " + device.deviceId);
    }   
  });
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

***** EDIT *****
See'sm my issue might be related to https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/discuss-webrtc/vrw44ZGE0gs/2YJ6yUEjBgAJ

WebRTC internally mixes the audio tracks and the audio for all of the tracks is actually delivered to Chrome as a single audio stream. Changes to properties such as volume, is sent into WebRTC to apply before mixing.  So, that unfortunately means that the output from that mixer can only be directed to a single audio device.

The above applies to  and  media elements.

However, there is a workaround available in Chrome, which involves rendering via WebAudio.  For this to work, audio still needs to be "pulled" from the mixed stream, even though it doesn't necessarily go to a particular device or is muted.
Then you can follow this example to clone the remote tracks and render them via WebAudio.

So Now I just need to figure out how to do this.

Comment: What language? What browser? What's a "player"? Maybe show some code?

Comment: I've updated my example. Hopefully, this is enough information now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to fix this issue. I created a function and looped the WebRTC audio through WebAudio using the following code:

```
    function addNewStream(event, dynamicSinkID, lang) {     
        var mediaStream = event.element.srcObject;
        var remote_stream1 = mediaStream.clone();
        test_audio_context1 = new AudioContext();
        webaudio_source1 = test_audio_context1.createMediaStreamSource(remote_stream1);
        webaudio_ms1 = test_audio_context1.createMediaStreamDestination();
        webaudio_source1.connect(webaudio_ms1);
        test_output_audio1 = new Audio();
        test_output_audio1.srcObject  = webaudio_ms1.stream;
        test_output_audio1.play();
        test_output_audio1.setSinkId(dynamicSinkID);
        test_output_audio1.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
        document.getElementById(lang).appendChild(test_output_audio1);
        test_output_audio1.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
        test_output_audio1.setAttribute("width", "300");
        test_output_audio1.setAttribute("height", "54");                          
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on how you achieved this? I have a similar issue with a voice chat with multiple participants. I want to allow each participant's audio to be routed to a dedicated output. But as soon as I change the output of one participant ALL of them are routed to the same sink.

Comment: You're just cloning the source of the event in the above description. Then set the sinkid you want. Lang could be omitted from my example above. When you duplicate a source, you can mute the original and set the new sinkid. Setting a sinkid on a clone you create will only change it and none of the others since you create it with that sinkid.